# Contact Fields in android

Tags: android

I am building an Android application where I need to detect the contact format (fields like name, lastname, DOB etc) from the user's Android handset. How do I do it?

Comment: Just googled, you can find many tutorial on that, Put some efforts on that..

Comment: I googled for "androids contacts fields" and this was the first result :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a link to the developers reference, it may help.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html